# Connecting to a SQL database in my project folder using connection string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf, connection

My SQL Server is running and I am trying to connect my database in my project folder. But it is not working rather it is showing an exception

> Network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.

Below is the code I am using to connect the database to my project.

```
public static string ConnectionString()
{
   string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);    
   string databasename = "riocomsat.mdf";    
   string me = "Data Source=(localdb)\vll.0;AttachDbFilename=" + path + @"\" + databasename + ";Integrated Security=True";    
   return me;
}
```

I really need your help.

Comment: There is a backslash in your string (first part), that isn't escaped.

Comment: please can you specify

Comment: Try replacing `vll.0` with `v11.0` (L => 1).

Comment: \ needs to be escaped in strings, either by writing \\ instead or by writing an @ in front of the string (as you did after path). (Good catch, @yaakov)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
Server=(localdb);Database=riocomsat;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Comment: Sorry I am not using a local database

Comment: Change (localdb) with your servers's ip @SMARTG.

Comment: @SMARTG.: You are "connect my database in my project folder" but you are not "using a local database"...? That's a contradiction.

Comment: If you use ssms pls show the servername, because it can be possible that you aren't using localdb. Instead you might used your servername as name.

Answer (score 1):

just use this

`Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;`